# Entity Framework 6 - fill property from another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a working project with an existing Database, models, and everything. 
I'm thinking of using EF6, but at the same time I'd like to keep the control.
And my problem is, I cannot solve the following problem.
I have these two models:

```
public class CMaster
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    public string DetailName { get; set; }
}
public class CDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Up till now I had a query, like this:

```
SELECT 
    m.ID,
    m.TITLE,
    m.IDDETAIL DetailId,
    (SELECT d.TITLE FROM DETAIL d 
WHERE d.ID = m.IDDETAIL) DetailName
FROM MASTER m
```

with this query I had one database run to query the *Master*, AND to query ONLY ONE record from the *Detail* table, that belongs to this *Master*.

I'm using Fluent API, and I've set things like:

```
public class CMasterDetailsContext : DbContext
{
    public CMasterDetailsContext(DbConnection existingConnection) : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection: false)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MYSCHEMA");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CMaster>().ToTable("MASTER");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CMaster>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CMaster>().Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CMaster>().Property(m => m.Title).HasColumnName("TITLE");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CMaster>().Property(m => m.DetailId).HasColumnName("IDDETAIL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CMaster>().Ignore(m => m.DetailName);


        modelBuilder.Entity<CDetail>().ToTable("DETAIL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CDetail>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CDetail>().Property(d => d.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CDetail>().Property(d => d.Title).HasColumnName("TITLE");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<CMaster> MasterEntries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CDetail> DetailEntries { get; set; }
}
```

I thought I should be able to map one property (Title) of my *Detail* table to one property (DetailName) of the *Master* table here in the *OnModelCreating* method.
I found [HasComputedColumnSql](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascomputedcolumnsql-method), but it exists only in EF Core.

Then I tried it like:

```
var oMasterEntriesFromLinqJoin = Enumerable.Join(oContext.MasterEntries, oContext.DetailEntries, m => m.DetailId, d => d.Id, (master, detail) =>
{
    master.DetailName = detail.Title;
    return master;
});
```

But in this case EF loads the entire *Details* table, then makes the join. That means two database runs, and in the first one the entire *Details* table will be loaded, what I want to avoid.
Is there any (elegant) solution?

Comment: `DetailName` property is not in the `CMaster` table looking at your query - get rid of it completely, you only need the `Title` property in the `CDetail` class

Comment: Plus, given the relationship, I would say you have the naming backwards. Your Master table contains the foreign key to the detail!

Comment: Yes it's a known redundancy, but it's on purpose. It's a situation I cannot change. Do you know a solution wiht the given circumstances?

Comment: @tretom have you found a solution? I need the same thing

Comment: @maskalek, unfortunately not. I gave up on it because it was against 'keep it simple' in my case. But still... ideas are welcome